# Determinate when last method has been called in method chaining

Tags: php, oop, method-chaining

I'm using something like this for a query builder:

```
$queryHandler = new QueryHandler($connection);
$queryHandler->insert("someDataHere")
             ->into("someTable")
             ->when("sleep", 1000);
```

I want it to execute the query when the last method has been called on that statement, which in this case is the `when` function.

```
/**
 * User: Bas
 * Date: 8-12-2014
 * Time: 20:11
 */
class QueryFunctions
{

    .....

    /**
     * @param int|float|string| $data The data which is getting inserted
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function insert($data) {
        ....
        return $this;
    }

    public function into($table, $execute) {
        ....
        return $this;
    }

    public function when($condition, $functionArgument) {
        switch($condition) {
            case "wait":
                .....
                break;
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * To prevent instantiation
     */
    private function __construct() {

    }
}
```

How can i do this?

Comment: put the insert only on when function o_0

Comment: I was just recently been thinking about the same problem with `C++` and `<<` operator. It doesn't seem to be possible without explicit call.

Comment: @MarcoMura Should it be good practice if i give an extra argument on each function named `execute` which is already set to `false`?

When the users give's that argument as a true, the query gets executed?

Comment: @TomášZato I dont know much about C++ and its operators, so i cant tell what you're saying :P

Comment: Sadly, there are no conventions for method-chaining in PSR till now.

Comment: @Bas i think that if the system is correctly setted you always need the execute so have an optional parameter won't give you any help. If i give you the data for the query i think that i need to run the query, don't you think it too?

Comment: @MarcoMura Nah, you dont need to set the `execute` function when calling the function then, its pre-set with something like this: `public function when($condition, $argument, $execute = false) {...}` Or dont you mean that?

Comment: @Bas i know how to give an optional parameter ($execute = false) but if i give you the data for the query, do you really need a var ($execute = true) to launch the query? If the system has the data it is demanding a launch, for me if i give the data for a query i've done it (giving the data) to launch it. What's the use if not?

Comment: @MarcoMura I guess that you dont have to call an extra method then? That it's happening automaticly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Nope... in general

I don't think you can know that the chain is over. Don't forget that your code is DIRECTLY equal to:

```
$queryHandler = new QueryHandler($connection);
$queryHandler->insert("someDataHere");
$queryHandler->into("someTable");
$queryHandler->when("sleep", 1000);
```

Even if such logic was possible it might not always be convenient. You might come accross a situation when you want to execute the *prepared* query *later*.

Instead, make another method to send the query:

```
$queryHandler->insert("someDataHere")
             ->into("someTable")
             ->when("sleep", 1000);
$queryHandler->start(); //will execute conditions (such as sleep) and then send query
```

#### Tick callback

There is creepy possible workaround using [`tick callback`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-tick-function.php) in PHP. You **could** assign a function first time *before* returning `$this` and then check, **in every tick** whether the code is still in scope of your class. Once you find out it isn't you could execute the query.

Creepy, but possible.

Comment: That's looking pretty good, but then we should check if the `when` function is called?

Comment: @Bas I supposed that if `when` wasn't called no conditions are evaluated and the query runs right away. Btw check the updated answer. What you want to do is possible but not recomended.

Comment: I've read it, but i rather use your first method then. It's similiar how i wrote my QuerySystem first (see http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/72054/oop-queryhandler-in-php). How do you like it when giving the execute parameter to functions?

Answer (score 2):

A common way is to invert the order of functions. Write:

```
$queryHandler->into("someTable")
             ->when("sleep", 1000)
             ->insert("someDataHere")
             ;
```

The `insert()` will trigger the query. I guess there is no other way in PHP except complex methods like workers or crontabs.

Comment: That would be a great idea, Thanks. but i dont like the way how we write it down.

Comment: Yes, it sounds a little German, with the verb at the end of the sentence -> into table when 1000 insert. Alternatively, use an `execute()` function or something like this.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. There is no way for your code to know if there's going to be any other calls made to the object. Use an `execute` method or something similar to actually perform the query.

You could use a destructor to run a piece of code when the object is going to be destroyed, but that will end up in a mess when statements are run in random-ish order, and usually not before the script has ended. So don't do that.